# How to silence errors inside a UDF?

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, user-defined-functions

I need to write a UDF that would try to cast a varchar to a bigint and return either that bigint or zero if failed. The problem is - I can't find a way to silence casting error when the string is not a valid number. TRY CATCH doesnt work inside functions and I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Create Function dbo.Convert2BigInt(@Data VarChar(100))
Returns BigInt
As 
Begin
    Return(Case When IsNumeric(@Data + '.0e0') = 1 
                Then Convert(BigInt, @Data)
                Else Convert(BigInt, 0)
                End)
End
```

Comment: It kind of works, in the way it doesn't give any errors, but if I pass "3uytutu" it returns 3 which is not correct.

Comment: That's weird.  When I call the function with the same value "3uytutu" it returns 0.  I ran: Select dbo.Convert2BigInt('3uytutu')

Comment: Did you make sure to specify the size of the varchar parameter?  In my code, I used the value 100.  If you leave that off, SQL Server defaults the size to 1 character, so your test value was getting truncated to one character, which is "3" and can safely be converted to a big int.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly that - i didn't have size for varchar :) It works, I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!